# Directive Does Not Inherit Controller's Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller set up which contains a few functions to do form validation. In this controllers $scope I have an array $scope.errorMsgs that is populated with strings of error messages the user makes when filling out the form.

I also have a directive that displays this form. They are both attached to the same module. The controller and directive are in separate files within the same directory. However the scope in the directive's link function does not reference the $scope in the controller. They have different $ids in fact. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

**Module:**

```
angular.module('aop.availabilitysolver', [
    'aop.services',
    'checklist-model'
]).run(['widgetService', function(widgetService) { 'use strict';
    widgetService.registerWidgets([
        {
            title: 'AVAILABILITYSOLVER.WIDGETS.AVAILABILITYSOLVER',
            translatableDescription: 'AVAILABILITYSOLVER.WIDGETS.AVAILABILITYSOLVER',
            type: 'aop-availability-solver',
            configuration: {},
            width: 1
        }
    ]);
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('aop.availabilitysolver')
    .controller('AvailabilitySolverController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) { 'use strict';
            //console.log($scope);
            $scope.selectGoalDropdown = ['Impressions', 'Spend'];
            $scope.selectGoalTimespan = ['Day', 'Week', 'Month'];

            $scope.selectGoals = [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'Impressions'
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    name: 'Spend'
                }
            ];

            $scope.selectTimespan = [
                {
                    id: '4',
                    name: 'Day'
                },
                {
                    id: '5',
                    name: 'Week'
                },
                {
                    id: '6',
                    name: 'Month'
                }
            ];
            $scope.selectedItem = 'test2';
            $scope.selectedItem1 = 'test3';

            $scope.per = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20];
            $scope.hours = [1, 3, 4, 12, 24, 36, 48, 72, 120, 168];
            $scope.uncpd = ['uncapped'];
            $scope.times = {
                amt: [],
                freq: [],
                uncapped: []
            };
            $scope.caps = [];

            $scope.quantity;

            $scope.level = 'Fcap';

            $scope.showErrors = false;
            $scope.errorMsgs = [];

            $scope.calculateFreqCaps = function(amt, freq, uncap) {
                var rtn = [];
                function isNothingSelected() { // No selections made
                    if(amt.length === 0 && freq.length === 0 && uncap.length === 0) {
                        rtn.push('Please choose frequency settings or select \'uncapped.\'');
                        $scope.errorMsgs.push('Please choose frequency settings or select \'uncapped.\'');
                    }
                }
                function malformedFrequencyOpts() { // Selected amount but no frequency & vice versa
                    if((amt.length > 0 && freq.length === 0) || (amt.length === 0 && freq.length > 0)) {
                        rtn.push('Please select both an amount and a frequency.');
                        $scope.errorMsgs.push('Please select both an amount and a frequency.');
                    }
                }
                function selectedTooMuch() { // Uncapped and frequency settings selected
                    if((amt.length > 0 || freq.length > 0) && uncap.length === 1) {
                        rtn.push('Choose uncapped only if no amount or frequency is selected');
                        $scope.errorMsgs.push('Choose uncapped only if no amount or frequency is selected');
                    }
                }
                isNothingSelected();
                malformedFrequencyOpts();
                selectedTooMuch();
                if(rtn.length > 0) {
                    return rtn;
                } else if (amt.length === 0 && freq.length === 0 && uncap.length === 1) { // Only uncapped selected
                    return ['uncapped'];
                }
                angular.forEach(amt, function (a) {
                    angular.forEach(freq, function (f) {
                        rtn.push(a + '/' + f + 'h');
                    });
                });
                return rtn;
            };

            $scope.validateSelectGoalQuantity = function(n) {
                if(!Number(n)) {
                    $scope.errorMsgs.push('Quantity must be a number');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            };

            $scope.submitBtnClick = function() {
                // Build Frequency cap JSON object
                $scope.caps = $scope.calculateFreqCaps($scope.times.amt, $scope.times.freq, $scope.times.uncapped);
                $scope.validateSelectGoalQuantity($scope.quantity);
                if($scope.errorMsgs.length > 0) {
                    console.log($scope.errorMsgs);
                    // Show error message div and clear $scope.errorMsgs
                    $scope.showErrors = true;
                    //$scope.errorMsgs.length = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.showErrors = false;

                }
            };
}]);
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('aop.availabilitysolver')
    .directive('aopAvailabilitySolver', ['$filter', function($filter) { 'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                angular.noop(attrs);
                // Hide error div initially
                $('.availabilitySolverErrorDisplay').hide();

                var i = element.find('.levelRadio :radio');
                i.on('click', function() {
                    if($(i[0]).prop('checked')) {
                        scope.level = 'Fcap';
                        element.find('.freqCapDiv').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        scope.level = 'Bid';
                        element.find('.freqCapDiv').hide();
                    }
                });
                console.log(scope);
            },
            templateUrl: 'features/availabilitySolver/availabilitySolver.html'
        };
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AvailabilitySolverController">
    <div class="container-fluid availabilitySolverScreen1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="alert alert-danger availabilitySolverErrorDisplay">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            Campaign Selector
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <!-- Goals -->
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Select Goal</h5>
            <form name="selectGoalForm" novalidate>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button name="goals" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="value.id as value.name for (key, value) in selectGoals" data-style="btn-primary" bs-select></button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="quantity">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        per
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button name="timespan" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="value.id as value.name for (key, value) in selectTimespan" data-style="btn-primary" bs-select></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- End goals -->
        &nbsp;
        <!-- Level cap -->
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Level</h5>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form class="levelRadio">
                    <input name="level" value="Fcap" type="radio" checked> Fcap &nbsp;
                    <input name="level" value="Bid" type="radio"> Bid
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end level cap -->
        &nbsp;
        <!-- Frequency cap analysis -->
        <div class="row freqCapDiv">
            <h5>Customize Frequency Cap for Analysis</h5>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <!-- per -->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in per">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   checklist-value="item"
                                   checklist-model="times.amt" /> {{item}} per
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- end per -->

                <!-- hour(s) -->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in hours">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   checklist-value="item"
                                   checklist-model="times.freq" /> {{item}} hr
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- uncapped -->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in uncpd">
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               checklist-value="item"
                               checklist-model="times.uncapped" /> uncapped
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
        </div><!-- end frequency cap analysis -->
        &nbsp;
        <!-- submit button -->
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitBtnClick()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why all the jQuery in directive? Everything within `link` could be done using angular built in directives like `ng-show` and `ng-model`

Comment: I'm new to Angular, still learning the 'Angular way.'

Comment: best way to learn is take jQuery out of the page. Once you start implementing data binding that whole directive could be turned into an `ng-include`

Comment: have to seee some html to see where scopes are being nested

Comment: I don't know what you have going on. I can't find that directive in html, only in `registerWidgets`. I have no idea what `registerWidgets`does. Suggest you make a demo in plunker to replicate issue.